# Which group of order 96 is this group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a group of order 96, and I am wondering which combination of familiar groups it might be. I have tried and failed to identify it with a semidirect product of cyclic groups.

$$G_1 = \langle a, b \mid a^8 = b^3 = (ab) ^2 = (a^2b^2)^3 = (a^4b^2)^3 = 1 \rangle$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you expect this group to be a nice combination of commonly considered groups? After all, there are 231 groups of order 96.

Comment: Not a precise reason. It arises as an automorphism group of a Riemann surface and I would like to know which of the 231 groups it is in order to compare it to some automorphism groups of related Riemann surfaces. I was unable to figure out how to specify enough information for GAP to identify the group.

Comment: GAP id's it as small group [96,64], and the structure description calls it ((C4 x C4) : C3) : C2

Comment: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/73/Dic6sC4.html

Comment: @Josh B. How did you specify the group to GAP?

Comment: Which Riemann surface? How do you know it is the automorphism group of that surface? Possibly a knowledge of the properties of the surface could help answer the question.

Comment: @the_fox That is [96, 94], not [96, 64], but this link is still very helpful.

Comment: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/73/C4%5E2sS3.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the GAP commands I used:

```
f:=FreeGroup("a","b");
a:=f.1;b:=f.2;
g:=f/[a^8,b^3,(a*b)^2,(a*a*b*b)^3,(a^4*b^2)^3];
IdGroup(g);
StructureDescription(g);
```

GAP reports this is small group [96,64] with structure description $((C_4\times C_4):C_3):C_2)$